# How to disable javascript not executing in iphone?

Tags: wordpress

I don't want to execute the script if the device is an iPad or iPhone. But it's showing error in the console. What is the reason for this?

```
<script>
    var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
    if (!agentID) {
        document.write('<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(). "/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"?>"></script>'";
    }
</script>
```

My current code is:

```
<script> var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
if (!agentID) 
document.write('<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(). "/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"?>"></script>'    
</script>
```

Comment: Could you tell what the error is?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: '"; } this code is displaying in webpage.

Comment: Why are you trying to execute php in JavaScript? You might want to check what your php is sending to the client; if imagine the error is there.

Comment: That php code is wordpress default function. get_template_directory_uri() means http://www.demo.com/test/. we cant get url without this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss some characters in your 4th line, try to edit this line.

You can also get the url in a specific var before your script in PHP, it'll be easier to avoid errors

```
$url = get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js";
...
<script> var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
if (!agentID) 
document.write('<script src="<?php echo $url ?>"></script>');    
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eshanel. Its working fine.we want to print the url <?php echo $url ?>.